# Neutron and mass-energy

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, neutrons

Neutrons and protons are particles and they have mass.
If mass and energy is interconvertible, then, why does nucleon number have to be conserved?

Comment: Baryon number $\frac{1}{3}(n_q-n_{\bar q})$ is (approximately) conserved

Comment: Just because mass and energy are interconvertible doesn't mean that they keep converting back and forth. There is a huge energy barrier for that to happen, it took as almost a century to come up with technology that can at least get near this barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Interconvertibility of mass and energy doesn't have anything directly to do with conservation laws like those governing charge, baryon number, isospin, lepton number, etc. except in the sense that when a nuclear reaction takes place, any mass deficit that is found to exist after the reaction is finished represents energy released by the reaction as photons or kinetic energy of the product particles.